# Intel Euclid GPS Compass

Tags: gps

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello community,

I'm evaluating the Intel Euclid SDK with ros and I miss some details to access the GPS  or magnetometer features.

Are there any special nodes for this features available for ros usage ?

Thanks in advance

Cheers

Chrimo

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/269682/intel-euclid-gps-compass/) by [ChriMo](https://answers.ros.org/users/23415/chrimo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 476 on 2017-08-27

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I found this information:

sudo /etc/init.d/cg2100_control.sh start

sudo gnssStelp NAF LBSSTARTPF 0 15 1000 1000

but no further documentation how to use api for programming a ros node.

---

Originally posted by [ChriMo](https://answers.ros.org/users/23415/chrimo/) with karma: 476 on 2017-09-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2017-09-03**:
What do you mean by

> how to use api for programming a ros node

?

Are you asking how to write a ROS node,  how to use the topics, services, etc. provided by the node, or something else?

**Comment by [ChriMo](https://answers.ros.org/users/23415/chrimo/) on 2017-09-03**:
I need to know something about the hardware api... e.g. how the gps or magnetsensor is connected to the system. e.g. i2c, intel integrated sensor hub. Intel Euclid has currently not released any hw specs.
If I find something about hardware interfaces, I'm able to prepare own ros node

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2017-09-03**:
It's difficult to find information on the Euclid, but this site is not going to be the place to find platform-specific information. Maybe try https://robotics.stackexchange.com if you couldn't find information from the links that I posted on your other question.

**Comment by [ChriMo](https://answers.ros.org/users/23415/chrimo/) on 2017-10-09**:
Intel delivers proprietary binaries only. They told me, "we are working at some nodes for ros" :-)